# Color interpolation with a set of 2D points

Tags: colors, interpolation

I am trying to modelize a physical problem of photoelasticity on a surface. I succeed to get an array of X,Y - coordinates of the surface and for each points I have a corresponding color in a RGB format. I used Python scatter to plot and the result is already great but there is still some discontinuities because of the lack of resolution that I can not improve :( I just wanted to ask how I can generate the same surface plot in a continuous way (with new "in-between" points for which the color of them have been interpolated with respect to the neighborhood points). I am not necessarily looking for coding it in python, every software is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this in javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/87nw05kz/

The important part is calculateColor. It finds the inverse square of the distance to each color from the pixel being shaded and it uses that to decide how much that pixel should be effected by each color.

```
function calculateColor(x, y) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        let c = colors[i];
        let d = distance(c.x, c.y, x, y);
        if (d === 0) {
            return c;
        }
        d = 1 / (d * d);
        c.d = d;
        total += d;
    }
    let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        let c = colors[i];
        let ratio = c.d / total;
        r += ratio * c.r;
        g += ratio * c.g;
        b += ratio * c.b;
    }
    r = Math.floor(r);
    g = Math.floor(g);
    b = Math.floor(b);
    return {r:r,g:g,b:b};
}
```